# CSV file, need to extract data, format data and convert to xml

Tags: python, xml, csv, extract, formatting

This is probably a really simple one, but i'm just getting back into the world of python.
I have a .csv file e.g.

```
FRAME, SEQID, CYCLE SEC, CYCLE COUNT, SIZE, GAMMA, GAIN0, GAIN1, GAIN2, GAIN3, GAIN4, GAIN5, SHUTTER0, SHUTTER1, SHUTTER2, SHUTTER3, SHUTTER4, SHUTTER5, LAT, LON, ALT, UTC
000000, 3371, 058, 0000, 3951616, 0.000, 64,64,64,64,64,64, 34,34,34,34,34,34, 52.53922000, 0.79127400, 48.300, 11:06:35.00
000001, 3372, 060, 0000, 3954176, 0.000, 64,64,64,64,64,64, 34,34,34,34,34,34, 52.53922033, 0.79127483, 48.400, 11:06:37.00
000002, 3373, 062, 0000, 3955200, 0.000, 64,64,64,64,64,64, 34,34,34,34,34,34, 52.53922050, 0.79127600, 48.400, 11:06:39.00
```

And I need to extract 'FRAME,LAT,LON' & then have it formatted like this in a .xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<viewpointlist>
   <viewpoint>
      <vpid>VP000001</vpid>
      <lat>52.5254</lat>
      <lng>0.70886</lng>
   </viewpoint>
   <viewpoint>
      <vpid>VP000002</vpid>
      <lat>52.5254</lat>
      <lng>0.70886</lng>
   </viewpoint>
```

As I said, probably a simple one, its been a long time.
Thank in advance.
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `csv` module to read csv file and `ElementTree` to create an xml:

```
import csv
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring 


root = Element('viewpointlist')
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        child = SubElement(root, "viewpoint")

        element = SubElement(child, 'vpid')
        element.text = line['FRAME']
        element = SubElement(child, 'lat')
        element.text = line[' LAT']
        element = SubElement(child, 'lng')
        element.text = line[' LON']

print tostring(root)
```

prints (indented for readability):

```
<viewpointlist>
    <viewpoint>
        <vpid>000000</vpid>
        <lat>52.53922000</lat>
        <lng>0.79127400</lng>
    </viewpoint>
    <viewpoint>
        <vpid>000001</vpid>
        <lat>52.53922033</lat>
        <lng>0.79127483</lng>
    </viewpoint>
    <viewpoint>
        <vpid>000002</vpid>
        <lat>52.53922050</lat>
        <lng>0.79127600</lng>
    </viewpoint>
</viewpointlist>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was after.